# Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-support-library

The error persists when i try to build my code. I have already provided latest versions  for all the implementations. Also i haven't used Analytics tool of firebase, but why is this error occurring ?

I have been updating the versions of the implementations one by one to mitigate several errors of such kinds.

my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ayushadarsh.odolog"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'

    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3'
}
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of your jar files have already implemented FirebaseAnalytics lib and you have reimplemented it with implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'

Comment: Could you accept my answer, if it helps? You might need to clean the project. I could not reproduce the `com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event` problem, but only a few others (and so I re-tagged the question accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be changed/updated to `play-services-base:16.1.0` (which is not bundled):

```
//noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
```

And remove this line; simply because painting the problem does not solve the problem:

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Libraries `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` & `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0` are also added twice. and this one  plugin belongs to the bottom of the `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

... this fixes the build:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3"

    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    }
    implementation ("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: " exifinterface"
    }

    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

change

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```